# Woocommerce Product Description repeating twice at top of page

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

The long product description is getting repeated at the top of the page? I am thinking it might be atheme error. I do not intend to remove the theme. Is there any way to fix it?
The page I need help with is https://trendyeverafter.co.in/product/womens-active-wear-2-piece-set-grey-seamless-high-waist-leggings-and-long-sleeve-crop-top/

Comment: What theme are you using? Have you used any page builder plugins like Elementor?

Comment: Yes, I'm using elementor plugin. The theme I'm using is Open Store by ThemeFarmer